# Serif font from Women’s Health article

Tags: font-identification, serif

This is a screenshot taken from a Women’s Health article:

[image]

I am trying to find the font used here. I tried using Whatthefont, and the ”font matcherator— on FontSpringfont with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like what you were looking for.  JosefinSlab-Regular

[image]

It is free for download here  http://www.ffonts.net/Josefin-Slab-SemiBold.font.download

Comment: Wow...I actually have the Josefin sans serif font already. This is a perfect match, thank you!